# Overflow with numpy.exp()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have to find 3 parameters with the leastsq function of scipy, as the procedure is described [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) in the part least-square fitting.

Here is my code:

```
def myFunc(t, Vs, Vi, k):
    y = Vs * t - ((Vs - Vi) * (1 - np.exp(-k * t)) / k)
    return y

x = np.array(temps, dtype='float64')
y = np.array(fluo, dtype='float64')

Vs, Vi, k = [2.8707e-11, 0.01241, 19765.39043]

def residuals(p, y, x):
    Vs, Vi, k = p
    err = y - myFunc(x, Vs, Vi, k) 
    return err

def peval(x, p):
    return myFunc(x, p[0], p[1], p[2])

p0 = [2.8707e-11, 0.01241, 19765.39043]
plsq = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(y, x))

print(plsq[0])
print(np.array([Vs, Vi, k]))
```

But I get the warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

I assume the number produced in exp is too big to fit in a `float64`. But I really need to make it fit. Is there any option to overcome this issue?

Comment: Considering normalizing your data (and function) first: your parameters are way out (each others) range, and that causes problems with any optimisation problem. Best is if you can scale things such that your (starting) parameters are of order 1.

Comment: you mean for example to multiply each y by 10e7, and dividing each x by  3600 ? what is the range of the exp function ?

Comment: I don't know what your input data (x and y) are, but something like that. Your fit (and starting) parameters will be different, but you can correct for that afterwards.

Comment: The range of `exp()` is whatever your `float64` can store, so take for example the `log()` of `numpy.finfo(numpy.float64).max` and you'll find out what is the maximum input value).

Comment: but there is nothing bigger than a flot64 ?

Comment: Don't try to get your answer by going bigger. Reformulate your problem and you'll get a better result. Your current problem, with the input you have, will fit badly on any machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to look at the input data (contained in your arrays `temps` and `fluo`) it's hard to say exactly, but I don't think this is something to worry about*. As [`scipy.optimize.leastsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq) works it optimizes a set of equations via the Jacobian and marches down to a local minimum. Along the way, *it is possible* that some of the values will overflow, these should be handled correctly with the optimizer. The warning comes from the first evaluation of the overflow, it may be happening more than once but it is only shown for the first time.

* Provided that you check your solution and verify that it is physical and gives a reasonable fit. The output from leastsq gives you a covariance of the parameter estimates which you can use to determine how well the fit progressed.

Comment: It seems the tip from Evert is a good one. I basically divided each of my x value per 3600 (they were seconds), and each of my y value were multiplicated by 10^7. Now, I have no more overflow, and the fitting curve is way much better. Now, I would like to now, how do I get back the REAL value of my parameters ? I can't simply do *3600 *10^(-7) it seems.

Comment: @user1585507 why not? By multiplying by a constant, you are simply performing a units transformation. Eg. you could fit in seconds, or 1/3600 secs (hours). Understand that the numbers themselves represent physical quantities **with units** and they can be transformed as such.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thougt as well, but the curve with the new parameters doesn't fit the data.

Comment: @user1585507 You probably didn't do a correct transformation back (I assume you want to e.g. plot your fit in the original input units). Keep in mind your function is non-linear; for example the parameter `k` appears in the exponent (where it gets scaled by 3600, being multiplied by `t`) but also also an (inverse) normalisation constant (where it gets scaled by the `10^7`). Use transformed parameters *and* input as well if you like to create eg. a best-fit line, then just before the plot, only then rescale everything back. And keep in mind what units you express the results in (as said above).

Comment: Ok, I can have a very beautiful fit line if I use the transformed inputs and the corresponding parameters. But I'm not sure to understand what you mean. My goal is to transform back the parameters. All of them, and then I'd like to use the new values to plot the fitline, with the original inputs. How do I get back k for example ? And Vs ? I tried by multiplying each of them by 10^-7 * 3600, but it gives irrelevant results.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you should consider turning all the huge variables into a global variables.That worked for me when i got stack overflow in visual studio(c++).

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Do you want to put everything in one variable ?

Comment: No just turn the variables that host a huge number into global variables(available and adjustable from everywhere in your program).Of course I may be mistaken but you could give it a try.

Comment: (-1) how is that going to help?

Comment: //Of course I may be mistaken but you could give it a try//.What exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: The OP is getting a *numeric* overflow, not a *stack* overflow. This is (bad) answer to another question.

Comment: (-1) what the? This isn't anywhere near a useful answer.